# jd-gui stops working when I try to save all resources

Tags: decompiling

I opened a jar file in jd-gui but when I try to save the all resources it stops working. I don't know where to look for the logs of jd-gui.

How can I save all the decompiled source files?

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem, and resoled it as below:

1. unzip the target jar file.
2. remove unnecessary folder
3. zip the remaining class files into a new-small jar file.
4. download the `jd-cli` project from here: https://github.com/kwart/jd-cli/releases/tag/jd-cli-1.2.0
5. use `jd-cli` to de-compile the jar , and with the log option, e.g.

   jd-cli target.jar -od jar_result -g ALL
6. check the output log and find out which `block.class` file block the de-compile proccess. if there is, then remove it from the `target.jar` and then re-run the `jd-cli` again. You can manually copy/paste the `block.class` source code from jd-gui.

Comment: It's not addressing the core issue but this workaround definitely worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Open "jd-gui.cfg" with a text editor. "LastUri", in section "Decompilation", contains the name of the CLASS file causing the crash. A workaround is to open the JAR file and remove or change extension of this CLASS file.

Regards.

Comment: Emmanuel, any news regarding the progress of your excellent java decompiler? I would really love to see a new version which fixes some annoying bugs.. (btw: where's the bug tracker? I am quite sure that I saw such a thing some years ago on your page...)

Comment: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ is no longer accessible (403 access denied). Is there any change of status for that excellent software? Did you upload it anywhere else?

Comment: Never mind: I just saw https://twitter.com/EmmanuelDupuy/status/217345334844723202 ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218792/cant-access-jd-eclipse-site-http-java-decompiler-free-fr-q-jdeclipse/11234175#11234175

Comment: And where is that cfg file located?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug. I solved it simply trying to export sources to other folder ($home -using debian-)

Answer (score 0):

1. open the target jar file with `archivator`
2. in `archivator` GUI just delete unnecessary folders
3. save if necessary
4. open modified `jar` in `jd-gui`
5. export all project in "`file menu`"