# Can't access JD-Eclipse site: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse

Tags: eclipse, decompiler

I can't access java decompiler site: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse.

It shows 403 error :

> Erreur 403 - Refus de traitement de la requête (Interdit - Forbidden)**.

I'm accessing it from China. Is anyone out of China can access it properly? Or it's the server issue?

**EDIT:**
The eclipse update site is hosted on [jd.benow.ca](http://jd.benow.ca).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience: my Webhost detects a virus in JD-Eclipse !

---

Votre page personnelle a été suspendue pour la/les raisons suivantes:

==> Your personal page has been suspended for/because:

Virus: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse.win32.x86_0.1.3.jar

---

This file has not changed since two years ! It contains an DLL library compressed with UPX and modified. Hackers and anti virus have some probems to decompress it.

Well, this situation is really uncomfortable. I will try to restore my website.

Emmanuel Dupuy, JD Projects.

Comment: For what it's worth, please consider open-sourcing this and throwing it up on Google Code or GitHub or such?  (I'd hate to see this project go the same way as JAD...)

Comment: @ziesemer I don't want to abandon projects JD : there are so many interesting points to improve: realigment of source code (algorithm is ready and the results are OK), decompile the try-with-resources statement, ...

Comment: Didn't mean to imply.  Thank you for all your efforts, past and upcoming.  I'd just be interested in helping if you were able to make the project open source - and I'm guessing others would as well.  I also know that many would be more interested in using JD if they knew that someone would be able to continue the project, just in case you ever were required to abandon it.

Comment: I can only second this! Since this is essentially a freeware/donationware, I think there would be nothing to lose and you would get free contributions in exchange.

Comment: I just noticed someone implemented realignment as a separate plugin, and also provides an update site containing both, see https://github.com/mchr3k/jdeclipse-realign

Comment: Details about my changes can be seen here: http://mchr3k-coding.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/realignment-for-jd-eclipse.html

Comment: @Emmanuel Dupuy I so badly want to use this decompiler from within my Java program... (it's a self modifying, source code collecting, artificial intelligence construct). Java Decompiler is absolutely the best Java decompiler available. Why can't I call the JD-Core .DLL files outside of Eclipse or IntelliJ? What resources are missing? I keep getting this for the decompiled methods: `/*     */   // ERROR //`

Comment: I still can't download it from his website?

Comment: Try http://jd.benow.ca

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same 403 error.

You can see a [previous version](http://web.archive.org/web/20110720221237/http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) of the site from archive.org.

If you want to install the Eclipse plugin you can download and unzip the [update site](http://web.archive.org/web/20110720221237/http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/jdeclipse_update_site.zip) from archive.org as well.

The eclipse update site is also hosted on [jd.benow.ca](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the bundles to my local.