# Is there a replacement for java.decompiler.free.fr?

Tags: java, decompiler

Searching in this site for a way to replace my long-lost Java source code with something reverse engineered from my old .class files, I found a reference to an online tool at http://java.decompiler.free.fr which worked great.

Now (6-sep-2013), hardly 2 weeks later, the site is gone (or being blocked by its ISP).

Any good replacements for this site/online-tool?

Comment: Recommendations for software are forbidden. But it looks like this software is still available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218792/cant-access-jd-eclipse-site-http-java-decompiler-free-fr-q-jdeclipse

Comment: Find the off line version.

Comment: Look at the answers to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files.  Or Google it ...

Comment: I thought I had asked for a mirror (i.e. replacement) site, which is not asking for a tool recommendation. I got the answer I was looking for by shakthydoss who was being helpful rather than dogmatic.

Comment: Free Java Decompiler [here](http://secureteam.net/Java-Decompiler.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JD tool http://jd.benow.ca/

Has GUI interface and available in eclipse via plugin.

Comment: I was able to access that site and installed the GUI app and Eclipse plug-in per the instructions on that web page. The standalone GUI works fine, but after multiple attempts, the Eclipse plug-in doesn't seem to have installed correctly. I have no "decompiler" showing up in the various views available. I wonder if it is because I am using newer Kepler WTP release? or JDK1.7? (on WinXP) I wonder because the install instructions did not match the dialog boxes I was actually presented with when installing the plug-in.

Comment: I fear that "java.decompiler.free.fr" is definitely closed. I've updated the list of miroires this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler

Comment: http://www.Decompiler.com/ is a nice one.